# Xcode - Can not update UILabel in NSTimer on tick

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, nstimer

I have a label that I want to update with the number of seconds that the user has left to complete a certain task. I decided to use an NSTimer which ticks every second, and calls the function updateTime(), which will decrement the property containing the # of seconds left, and then update the label. However, the label is not being updated. I get no errors, nor output. Anything I try to change with the label within updateTime() does not work: mylabel.text, mylabel.frame, mylabel.font, etc... Anywhere else though, I'm able to modify the label normally. Here is my code:

```
// ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSTimer* timer;
    int secs;

    UILabel* timerText;
}

@end

// ViewController.m
- (void)updateTime
{
    secs--;
    timerText = (UILabel*)[self.view viewWithTag:4]; // i have also tried putting this line in viewDidLoad. i also tried removing the property in the .h file and just doing UILabel* timerText = ....
    NSString* updatedTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", secs];
    timerText.text = updatedTime;
}

- (IBAction)startButton_pressed:(id)sender {
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(updateTime)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
}
```

EDIT: I am getting a "-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error now. `NSLog(@"%@", timerText)` outputs ">" so it is not null. Under this, I get "-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9767b60
" What is going on? What should I do about this? I tested similar code on a fresh project and it worked, no idea what's going on here. Could having two view controllers in my project possibly be causing this?

Comment: Have you logged timerText to see if it's nil? Also, scheduledTimer... already adds the timer to the run loop, you shouldn't add it manually.

Comment: For starters, by using `scheduledTimer...` you don't need to add your timer to a runloop.  That's the point of the "scheduled" part.  Not sure how it will react to being requeued.  Have you verified that `updateTime` is being called?  According to the reference, it should have the signature `updateTime:(NSTimer*)timer`.

Comment: @David it's optional to have the timer argument.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer How is it optional?

Comment: Yeah the code should work, provided the control the OP wants to use has a tag of `4` (better is to keep a reference to the control, which he implies he has given he stores the reference in an instance variable)...

Comment: @Eonil NSTimer will still call your selector as `updateTime` or `updateTime:(NSTimer *)timer` they both will work.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer It now works doesn't mean that's correct, and possibly to be broken eventually. You need a formal clue to support your claim.

Comment: @Eonil whoops never read the NSTimer docs, although there are posts all over stackoverflow without the timer argument, I stand corrected :)

Comment: @Eonil for example, target-actions may have 0-2 params and that's fine to use w/e form you wish

Comment: I've removed the NSRunloop and changed `updateTime` to `updateTime:(NSTimer*)timer`, but still getting the problem :/ Now I'm getting this runtime error: "-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" on this line: `timerText.Text = updatedTime;`

Comment: Please see my updates on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your replies everyone. I fixed it by creating a second ViewController class and putting all the initializations in its viewDidLoad.

Comment: It's great to hear you've fixed it, but please tag your answer as the correct answer so that other ppl can realise this question is fixed and this is the answer! :)